# How to Create ImageOptimize in mvc4(getting error)?

Tags: image, image-processing, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all i am working in mvc4 when writing a code for image optimization content showing the error i need to do this any body plz help me to solve this iam getting this error

here is my code:Controllers

```
 public ActionResult Uploading(ImageModel model)
        {
            var uploadFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            uploadFolder = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss/fff"));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);
            var streamProvider = new PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider(uploadFolder);

             Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                foreach (var uploadedFile in Directory.GetFiles(uploadFolder))
                {

                    var medium = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "medium-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
                    var thumbnail = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "thumb-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
                    ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, thumbnail, 100, 100);
                    ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, medium, 50, 50);
                }
                return new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("File uploaded.")

                };

            });
           return View("Upload", model);

        }
```

and here is my index page :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploading", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
     <input type="file" name="ImageUploaded" id="btnUpload" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"  />
 <button type="submit"  id="Upload">Upload</button>
     <br />
     //@Html.DisplayForModel(@ViewData["Time"]);        
     <label>@ViewData["Time"]</label>

 }
```

here iam getting an error at Content :HTTPRequestBase doesnot contain defnation for content

```
       Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
```

could any body help me to solve the problem thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below line in your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action Name", "Controller Name", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Because you are uploading the file, you are required to define the above line of code.